# cyclic rotation codility c++ solution

Tags: c++, vector, solution

I am trying to solve this problem [in Codility](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/2-arrays/)...
Here is the code:

```
 #include <iostream>    
 #include <vector>     
 #include <algorithm>
 using namespace std;

 vector<int> solution(vector<int> &A, int k);
 vector<int> A;   
 A.push_back(3);    
 A.push_back(5);   
 A.push_back(7);   
 A.push_back(9);   
 A.push_back(2);
 int k;
 rotate(A.rbegin(),A.rbegin()+k, A.rend());
```

While my compiler compiles and run with no problem, codility shows me that "error: 'A' does not name a type".
This is the code using to my compiler to check it:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
  #include <algorithm>
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
   vector<int> myVector;
   myVector.push_back(3);
   myVector.push_back(5);
   myVector.push_back(7);
   myVector.push_back(9);
   myVector.push_back(2);
   for(unsigned i=0;i<myVector.size();i++)
   {
     cout<<myVector[i]<<" ";
   }
   cout<<endl;
   int k;
   cout<<"Insert the times of right rotation:";
   cin>>k;
   rotate(myVector.rbegin(),myVector.rbegin()+k, myVector.rend());
   for(unsigned i=0;i<myVector.size();i++)
   {
     cout<<myVector[i]<<" ";
   }
  }
```

Compiler output:

```
func.cpp:9:3: error: 'A' does not name a type
   A.push_back(3);
   ^
func.cpp:10:3: error: 'A' does not name a type
   A.push_back(5);
   ^
func.cpp:11:3: error: 'A' does not name a type
   A.push_back(7);
   ^
func.cpp:12:3: error: 'A' does not name a type
   A.push_back(9);
   ^
func.cpp:13:3: error: 'A' does not name a type
   A.push_back(2);
   ^
func.cpp:16:9: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   rotate(A.rbegin(),A.rbegin()+k, A.rend());
         ^
func.cpp:18:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
 }
 ^

Detected some errors.
```

Comment: Did you forget `main()` ?

Comment: Hint:  use the `%` operator, such as `next_slot = (next_slot + 1) % total_slots;`

Comment: You show error message `func.cpp:18:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token`, yet, there is no such line in your code. How can that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had lot of problem and made some assumption
Here is the working code

1.You don't need to create a new vector as the function has already a referenced vector &A so any change will directly reflect to the original vector

2.value K is points of rotation which is already input to the function (so no need of cin)

got it 100% now

```
// you can use includes, for example:
// #include <algorithm>

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// cout << "this is a debug message" << endl;
#include<algorithm>


vector<int> solution(vector<int> &A, int K)
{
    if (A.empty() || A.size() == 1)
    {
        return A;
    }
    K = K % A.size();

    if (K == 0)
    {
        return A;
    }
    std::rotate(A.rbegin(), A.rbegin() + K, A.rend());
    return A;
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: i submitted and took 62%.

Comment: @alekastyl  Do select the answer if helped or upvote

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use rotate function from `<algorithm>`.

Results given by Codility:

```
Programming : C++
Task Score: 100%
Correctness: 100%
Performance: Not assesed
```

The solution:

```
vector<int> solution(vector<int> &A, int K)
{
    vector <int> shift;
    if (A.empty()) // check for empty array
        return {};
    if (K > A.size()) //if K bigger then size of array 
        K = K%A.size();
    if (K<A.size())
        K=A.size()-K; //normalize K to the position to start the shifted array
    if (K == A.size()) //if K= size of array, avoid any computation.
        return A;
    for (unsigned int i=K; i<A.size(); i++)
    {
        shift.push_back(A[i]);
    }
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<K; i++)
    {
        shift.push_back(A[i]);
    }
    return shift;
}
```

Comment: I would check the condition "if (K == A.size())" before the condition "if(K > A.size())". It would increase the code's performance as one would not check 2 extra conditions in case K is equal to A.size().

Answer (score 1):

**OBJECTIVE-C SOLUTION O(n*k) - One By One Approach**

**Results given by Codility**

Task Score: 100%
Correctness: 100%
Performance: Not assesed

**Time Complexity**

The worst case time complexity is O(n*k)

[Xcode Solution Here](https://github.com/jmanuelmosso/CSWarmingInterview/blob/master/CSWarmingInterview/CodilityChallenges/Arrays/CyclicRotation.m)

```
+(NSMutableArray*)byByOneSolution:(NSMutableArray*)array rotations:(int)k {
    // Checking for edge cases in wich the array doesn't change.
    if (k == 0 || array.count <= 1) {
        return array;
    }

    // Calculate the effective number of rotations
    // -> "k % length" removes the abs(k) > n edge case
    // -> "(length + k % length)" deals with the k < 0 edge case
    // -> if k > 0 the final "% length" removes the k > n edge case
    NSInteger n = array.count;
    NSInteger rotations = (n  + k % n ) % n;


    /******** Algorithm Explanation: Naive Method ********/
    // Rotate one by one based on the efective rotations
    for (int i = 0; i < rotations; i++) {
        id last = array[n-1];
        [array removeLastObject];
        [array insertObject:last atIndex:0];
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only define or declare symbols outside function. Your `A.push_back(3);` etc is not a definition or declaration statement. That's why you get the funny error message: definitions and declarations start with a type, and since the lines are outside of function, compiler expects to see a type, which `A` is not.

So you need a function, something like:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <vector>     
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<int> solution(vector<int> &A, int k)
{ //added
    //vector<int> A; // this is function argument, not local variable   
    A.push_back(3);    
    A.push_back(5);   
    A.push_back(7);   
    A.push_back(9);   
    A.push_back(2);
    //int k;  // this is function argument, not local variable
    rotate(A.rbegin(),A.rbegin()+k, A.rend());
    return A; // Added since the function needs to return a vector of int...
} //added
```

That should compile and do something. So what I did was what you probably intended to do: The code is in `solution` function now.

Comment: I think he mistakenly put a semicolon after `solution` instead of defining it. Thus the code that is failing to compile was supposed to be inside the curly braces of the function.

Comment: Thanks for your help but codility gives 0% with these codes.

Comment: @alekastyl Did you try my solution

Comment: @HariomSingh Your solution has tha same errors as mine as codility said. Codility does not need int main ().

Comment: @I didn't put Int main in my solution

Comment: @alekastyl I was able to execute in codility

Comment: sorry guys i get lost with the answers and comments here. hyde same problem with mine, @hariom singh 62% now.The compilation may be successful but gives 62%.

Comment: @alekastyl Edited the answer. This is possibly what you want. Or at least close to it. Good luck with your codility!

Comment: I think your code will break if K > N because `A.rbegin()+k` will be out of range.

Comment: @HCSF Sure, same way `A[k]` will break if `k` is out of bounds. Generally in C++, it's responsibility of the caller (of `solution` in this case) to not pass invalid arguments. If there was to be error checking, then it would probably be via exception, but that goes out of the scope of the question fast.

Answer (score 0):

**OBJECTIVE-C SOLUTION O(n) - Reverse Based Solution**

**Results given by Codility**

Task Score: 100%
Correctness: 100%
Performance: Not assesed

**Time Complexity**

The worst case time complexity is O(3n) => O(n)

[Xcode Solution Here](https://github.com/jmanuelmosso/CSWarmingInterview/blob/master/CSWarmingInterview/CodilityChallenges/Arrays/CyclicRotation.m)

```
+(NSMutableArray*)reverseBasedsolution:(NSMutableArray*)array rotations:(int)k {

    // Checking for edge cases in wich the array doesn't change.
    if (k == 0 || array.count <= 1) {
        return array;
    }

    // Calculate the effective number of rotations
    // -> "k % length" removes the abs(k) > n edge case
    // -> "(length + k % length)" deals with the k < 0 edge case
    // -> if k > 0 the final "% length" removes the k > n edge case
    NSInteger n = array.count;
    NSInteger rotations = (n  + k % n ) % n;

    /******** Algorithm Explanation: Reverse Based ********/
    // 1.- Reverse the whole array
    // 2.- Reverse first k numbers
    // 3.- Reverse last n-k numbers

    // 1. Reverse the whole array
    NSArray* reversed = [[array reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

    // 2. Reverse first k numbers
    NSRange leftRange = NSMakeRange(0, rotations);
    NSArray* leftPart = [[[reversed objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:leftRange]] reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

    // 3. Reverse last n-k numbers
    NSRange rightRange = NSMakeRange(rotations, n - rotations);
    NSArray* rightPart = [[[reversed objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:rightRange]] reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

    // Replace objects in the original array
    [array replaceObjectsInRange:leftRange withObjectsFromArray:leftPart];
    [array replaceObjectsInRange:rightRange withObjectsFromArray:rightPart];

    return  array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible C++ implementation with 100% total score:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

vector<int> solution(vector<int> &A, int K) {
    vector<int> ret;
    
    if (!A.empty()) {
        int kReal = K % A.size();
        std::copy(A.begin()+A.size()-kReal, A.end(), std::back_inserter(ret));
        std::copy(A.begin(), A.begin()+A.size()-kReal, std::back_inserter(ret));
    }
    return ret;
}
```